# BigQuery: cast integer column as date interval and add to date column

Tags: google-bigquery

Using Google BigQuery Standard SQL, I have a date column, and another column that is numeric. I would like to cast the numeric column as an interval (say date or year) and then add this to another date column. So...

```
ColA,ColB

'2015-01-01',2
```

would be used as: `date_add(ColA interval colB years) -> '2017-01-01'`

I'm trying to convert my date column, ColA to it's 2017 date equivalent. Is this the correct approach, or is there a more direct function/operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT '2015-01-01' AS colA, 2 AS colB
)
SELECT DATE_ADD(CAST(colA AS DATE), INTERVAL colB YEAR) AS new_dt
FROM yourTable
```

output is

```sql
new_dt   
----------
2017-01-01
```

Comment: This helped me with my problem I am working on now. Thank you for contributing to this community with your knowledge. Upvoted you answer

Comment: thank you @Arsik36 - glad to see that my old answers are still helpful :o)